# Gsheet - Split Values of Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm using

```
=importjson to import this API ("https://bitmax.io/api/pro/v1/depth?symbol=RUNE/USDT")
```

in a cell of Gsheet documents.
The result is this:

[image: Result]

Is there a way to split the value in a cell in this way?

This way to format the result of API call

[image: This way to format the result of API call]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP("X";{"X"\SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(G7;",";"|");".";",");"|")};SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(G7;",";"|");".";",");"|"))/2;2;2);0))
```

If that doesn't work, it'd help if you shared a sample sheet.

Comment: https://ibb.co/0qJ01QQ

Seems that there is problem with point ( " . "  ) because first column output is wrong while second column output is okay

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nnh4fgVHLlQx1UBN9XhEAm_atI3N7v92tSkVFDerA1s/edit?usp=sharing

This is a sample sheet

Comment: Can you make the sheet editable?

Comment: Done, sorry! Thank you

Comment: I used two SUBSTITUTE() formulas to swap the decimals "." (UK) for the decimals "," (Euro) before doing the split.  That seems to have worked.  I've updated my formula in my answer.  Take a look and see if that's better?

Comment: Awesome Matt!Super thank you! <3